# Rational approximation of tanh(x) function.

Tags: calculus, approximation

At https://youtu.be/i9GMuk0gffM?t=22m31s the author needed to approximate $tanh(x)$ using rational functions and absolute values. He constructed $\frac{x+2x^3}{1+|x+2x^3|}$ which was better than Padé (2,2)-approximation. The Padé approximation doesn't have the correct asymptote.

I felt amused by the approximation and thought about how to generalize this kind of approximation. I found no generalization so far. What would be the generalization of this kind of approximation?

Comment: I saw $\dfrac {x+2x^3}{1+|x+2x^3|}$ instead.

Comment: You can just use the taylor series of $x\mapsto\sinh(x)$ and $x\mapsto\cosh(x)$.

Comment: cant you use the continued fraction $\frac{z}{1 + \frac{z^2}{3 + \cdots}}?$

Comment: I know I\`m late to the party, but I found an [even better one](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+%28x%2B2x%5E3%29%2F%281%2B%7Cx%2B2x%5E3%7C%29+-+tanh%28x%29%2C+%28sgn%28x%29+-+sgn%28x%29%2F%281+%2B+%7Cx%7C%281.125+%2B+73%2F32x**2%29%29%29+-+tanh%28x%29%2C+x%3D-5%2C5+y%3D-0.04%2C0.04): $\mathbb{sgn}(x) - {\mathbb{sgn}(x)\over{1+|x|\left(1.125 + {73 \over 32}x^2\right)}}$. No mathematical rigour behind my approach, just a couple dozen minutes of experiments.